# Merging dataframe rows with text, numeric, and NA values

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, na

I have a dataframe like the one below (though much larger).

| name | age | sex | favcolor | grade | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tim | NA | NA | blue | 12 | 100 |
| tim | 18 | male | red | 12 | 50 |
| dave | 17 | male | red | 12 | 85 |
| mike | 15 | male | green | 10 | 95 |
| john | 12 | male | NA | 7 | 80 |
| john | 12 | NA | orange | 7 | 90 |

There are a few things I want to do. My primary goal is to merge the rows by the name variable, such that each name gets one row. Second, when merging rows, I want cells with data to override cells that are NA (tim with `age` and `sex`. Third, if the rows that are merging both have text values (e.g. tim with `favcolor`), I want to keep the first one. And lastly, for rows that both have values in numeric columns (`age`, `grade`, and `score`), I want the new value to be the mean of the merging rows.

If all these rules are followed, the dataframe should look something like this.

| name | age | sex | favcolor | grade | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tim | 18 | male | blue | 12 | 75 |
| dave | 17 | male | red | 12 | 85 |
| mike | 15 | male | green | 10 | 95 |
| john | 12 | male | orange | 7 | 85 |

Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this? I've tried about 30 different things, but it never turns out the way I want it to. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `group_by(name)` and use `summarize` to collapse the rows into a single one.

Finally, `relocate` to reorder the columns as the input.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarize(across(where(is.numeric), ~ mean(.x, na.rm = T)),
            across(where(is.character), ~.x[!is.na(.x)][1])) %>% 
  relocate(colnames(df))

# A tibble: 4 × 6
  name    age sex   favcolor grade score
  <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 dave     17 male  red         12    85
2 john     12 male  orange       7    85
3 mike     15 male  green       10    95
4 tim      18 male  blue        12    75
```